# Push footer to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, position, footer, absolute

The site structure is as follows - there is a common unit (content), which houses all of the elements of the site and the second unit, a footer which is to be pressed against the bottom of the site.

Content block is `position: absolute` for aligning the center (horizontal) - to decrease the screen when it is uniformly left for right and left its borders. The problem is that with such a block structure the footer doesn't stay pressed against the bottom of the page. Here's the code :

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.a_wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -300px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px dotted #000000;
}

.a {
  height: 800px;
}

.b {
  width: 90%;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class = "a_wrapper">
    <div class = "a"></div>
</div>
<div class = "b">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0k979ud5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things causing this - because of using only absolutely positioned elements, which takes them out of document flow, the `body` element itself has no height. So that would need to be set the same as the content. Then the footer is positioned according to the nearest positioned element, also because of `position: absolute`. It's direct parent is `body` which has no positioning so it will default to the `window` object. To solve this, `body` should be given `position: relative` :

```css
body {
  height: 800px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.a_wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -300px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px dotted #000000;
}

.a {
  height: 800px;
}

.b {
  width: 90%;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="a_wrapper">
    <div class="a"></div>
</div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

It the footer should be *below* the content, `body` would have to be 850 pixels high of course...